# Autodetection of JPA entities from JBoss module

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jboss, jboss-eap-6, persistence.xml

I have an EJB module **M**, contained in an EAR module.

**M** has a dependency on a jar file **data-model.jar**, installed as a *JBoss module* and correctly loaded using the *jboss-deployment-structure.xml* file.

The module works without any problems, but I cannot help adding every single entity as a `<class>` tag in persistence.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">

<persistence-unit name="persistenceUnitName" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <jta-data-source>java:/datasource</jta-data-source>

    <class>com.bla.persistence.entity.EntityOne</class>
    <class>com.bla.persistence.entity.EntityTwo</class>
    ...
```

So the question is: **is there a way to specify the persistent managed classes associated with a persistence unit loading them from a JBoss module, without adding them all as class tags in persistence.xml?**

By default the persistence unit is associated with *the annotated managed persistence classes contained in the root of the persistence unit* (*e.d.* the jar file the persistence.xml is in) ([docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16439_01/doc.1013/e13981/cfgdepds005.htm)).

I have tried adding:

```
<exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
```

but it does not change anything (I have read that Java EE applications use this value as a default anyway).

I could also use:

```
 <jar-file>?</jar-file>
```

but I don't know how to refer to the JBoss module (and hardcoding the name of the module's file seems a very bad practice to me).

Working with:

- JBoss EAP 6.4
- Hibernate 4.2.18
- JPA 2

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to add entities as `<class>` tags in persistence.xml

Just add auto-scan parameter in persistence.xml

```
<!-- Scan for annotated classes and Hibernate mapping XML files -->
<property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class, hbm" />
```

In order this to work persistence.xml and entity objects should be in same classpath.

If you dont have persistence.xml in same classpath as entities add this configuration in persistence.xml

```
<persistence ...>
<persistence-unit ...>
    <jar-file>${project.build.outputDirectory}</jar-file>
    ...
</persistence-unit>
```

Comment: I did that and it still doesn't find the entities. Any idea?